# Get utf8_general_ci varchar records from MySQL database with special characters returns null

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having `null` returned when a record contains special characters in the database.

For simplicity of an example the database looks like this:

```
ID        Integer        PRIMARY KEY, AUTO_INCREMENT
Name      varchar(20)    NOT NULL, utf8_general_ci
```

---

```
ID        Name
1         Blop
2         Blaap
3         Bluup
```

Now, SO doesn't seem to support the usage of for example a 'u' with an umlaut, so for this example, **just imagine that 'Bluup' has two u's with umlauts**.

If I run the query `GET * FROM names` then the result I receive in my `$.get` function:

```
[object]
    1 [object]
        id   : 1
        name : Blop
    2 [object]
        id   : 2
        name : Blaap
    3 [object]
        id   : 3
        name : null
```

When dumping the data using `var_dump` I found that the result is also already `null`.

So either PHP doesn't like getting strange characters or MySQL doesn't even return them to the PHP. I've been looking for an answer to this for the past few hours but can't find one.

I can't go and manually, or with a query, change all of the records with special characters as the data isn't mine to change.

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set on the mysql connection :

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

To better understand how encodings work i strongly recommend [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: What do you mean with "set on the mysql connection", do you mean that it must be included when creating the connection to the database so that it uses `utf8` for all queries? Btw, good article :)

Comment: Run the query `SET NAMES utf8;` after each time you connect to your database. It's also possible to set this as a default on the server if that's easier.

Comment: like @MichaelMior well pointed out: in php when you are creating the mysql connection this should be the first query you execute

Comment: Cool thank you, added it after the connection string and straight away fixed. Been at it for 4 hours straight so thank you very much!!! :)

For those concerned about security (read quite a few times that it makes the connection susceptible to sql injection), the whole application will be replaced in the coming weeks, based on a more secure framework.